# Use of global variable in never ending service

Tags: java, android, android-service

I created a never ending `service` but I'm not sure that it's OK to do what I did with this `service`. I declared global variable like `static String list_contact`
and fill the list from a `db` in `onCreate` method. I wanted to avoid to retrieve `data` from database each time because I need to compare to the list fast. But maybe it's a problem to store `data` in global variable of `Service`. Plus I  need another list with thousands of data. If it's no good, can I find a compromise between `memory` and `speed` for retrieving data ? Thanks.

Comment: Just a little terminology thing, there are no global variables in Java.  The scope of that variable is the class where it's declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a great idea put the static variable in Service and assume that service would run forever.

The biggest drawback is, service won't run in background forever, starting from Android O. Latest version applies more restrictions on the background processing and kills your service few minutes after app is put in background.

You can implement [Object pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) which will store the frequently accessed data in an Object. This doesn't require to have a service running and could serve your purpose. You need to ensure that you are not maintaining sensitive data in clear text in these Objects.

Alternatively, you can also read [this](https://medium.com/@appmattus/caching-made-simple-on-android-d6e024e3726b) post which describes caching for Android.

Comment: So i can create a pool of sqlite connection and firebase realtime database connection. But after a certain time the object are freed no ? and when i'll need them it will take time to be created no ?

Comment: You shouldn't create pool for Sqlite connections but rather you will load the data from database in Object Pool. Whenever you want to access it, you can just refer to in memory data rather than fetching data again. Since its a Singleton it should stay in memory as long as your app's process is running.

Comment: so i should start my app at reboot and the process is running until destroy is called when the user closed the app ?

Comment: Yes, the process is running until user is interacting with your app or you app is running in background. You can trigger your app whenever you want. But if your intention behind triggering app is just to initialize data, then you shouldn't do it. Perform lazy loading of data i.e. load the data whenever it is needed for the first time. Then maintain in object. Be extremely picky when it comes to determine, which data you want to put in memory.

Comment: Ok i'm going to implement this but the first time it will load the datas it will be longer. I'll hope they let the app in background maybe i should advise them to keep in background as most as possible it's for messaging app.

Comment: You can refer to https://medium.com/@appmattus/caching-made-simple-on-android-d6e024e3726b for more ideas. I will update it in answer too